# Failing compilation with lint warnings for specific android files

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

Would like to fail code compilation on few specific files not for full module with any lint warning. One warning example -
[image]

Could you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you receive the result of the method beforehand in a variable and the check if it is not null pass it to the next.

Comment: This is just a simple example. Files are generally having multiple different warnings and requires different fixes. Null check is not the only requirement

Comment: When you generate a release build Gradle will fail if some serious lints are there in one or more files.

Comment: Need to fail build at the development time once we build using android studio and want to constraint the failures for few classes not for whole module. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: [This](https://android.jlelse.eu/writing-custom-lint-rules-and-integrating-them-with-android-studio-inspections-or-carefulnow-c54d72f00d30) may help